# How do you use mvvm-light to trigger gotfocus

Tags: silverlight, focus, mvvm-light

Using silverlight, we are looking to move the focus to a textbox. 
How do you use mvvm-light to trigger gotfocus?
The view contains:

```
<TextBox Margin="4,4,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=SearchOID, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GotFocusCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

1. How should the ViewModel look?
2. How do you trigger this from the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a TriggerAction, very similar to:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42988/Silverlight-Behaviors-and-Triggers-Making-a-Trigge.aspx